# Can Tag Manager be used for Demographic reporting in Mobile App Analytics?

Tags: android, ios, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

Is it possible to to enable AdvertisingId/IDFA collection through GTM to get Demographic reporting in GA (Mobile App Analytics)?

If not, and GA SDK must be used, will events have to be sent via the Tracker to get demographic reporting, or can GTM still be used for events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in the newest version of the Google Tag Manager, you only need to activate the **Enable Advertising ID Features** in the Universal Analytics tag itself:

> Includes App Install Conversions, Demographics and Interest Reports and Remarketing with Google Analytics Integration. Learn about App Install Conversions, Demographics and Remarketing and their impact on your privacy policy.

[image: Google Tag Manager Configuration with Demographic Reporting]

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, its possible as long as you include the libAdIdAccess.a library and set the allowIDFACollection to true in the GTM GA tracker

Comment: How to "set the `allowIDFACollection` to true in the GTM GA tracker" if `TAGDataLayer *dataLayer = [TAGManager instance].dataLayer; [dataLayer push:@{...}];` is being used (not GAI.h)? Thanks

Comment: If you enable that in iOS beware that your app will be rejected unless you also have an ad platform serving ads within your app.

Comment: @msrdjan you are right - Looks like GA SDK is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering my own question, but I am going to have to answer with 'no'. The current [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) does not expose any parameters for Demographic reporting.
At this time, you need the GA SDK to get Demographic reports in iOS and Android.

Comment: With the measurement protocol, is it possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875097/how-to-use-the-advertising-id-in-the-google-measurement-protocol/42205880#42205880