# How to use the Advertising ID in the Google Measurement Protocol

Tags: google-analytics, protocols, measurement, google-advertising-id

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846108/how-to-get-advertising-id-in-android) replies very well to the question "How to get Advertising ID in android?"...

but not **how** to use it.

I would like to know **what** is the [parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) to be used in the Google Measurement Protocol to transfer that advertising ID the Google endpoint and get demographic insights in my GA dashboards (on https://analytics.google.com/).

Do I have to send it with the client id ("cid")?

Or, to make it simple, what is the parameter used by the SDK on iOS and Android?

Comment: Hello @Gilbou, i'm trying to do exactly the same, i tried by using the cid but it doesn't seems to work, did you managed this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the name of the parameter is "**adid**" for Android (and not "aaid"), as demonstrated by the screenshot below (request made by the GA SDK in a demo app).

[image]

It also appears (you see it on the screenshot) that the "**ate**" parameter must be sent with the advertising ID (ate=1 if the ads targeting is ON ; ate=0 if ads targeting in OFF) for the advertising ID to be taken into consideration by Google Analytics.

This implementation was tested and I can confirm that it works.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for this answer the parameter is &adid for android (&idfa for iOS). You also apparently have to send the store ID in the &aiid field (ex : com.android.vending for google play) and the app ID in the &aid field.

So basically in an android app hit you have &adid=abcde-fghij-klmno-pqrst-uvwxy&aiid=com.android.vending&aid=com.yourapp.android

Still testing to get the demographic report working with server side requests.

Comment: Hi! Did it work? Is it "adid" or "aaid" for Android?